# BigQuery connection for Power BI through ODBC drivers

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery, odbc, database-connection, powerbi

I am facing an issue while trying to connect BigQuery to Power BI using Simba ODBC driver. Does anybody faced an issue like this and can help me with it? Any help or suggestion is appreciated! Thank you very much in advance!

On BigQuery, I have a table which is connected directly from Google Sheets using its URL. First I tried to connect BigQuery or Google Sheets to Power BI but it gave me authentication errors. Then I learned that I can use ODBC drivers to prevent this issue. I downloaded and configured the driver and tested, it worked successfully. Then I created the connection through ODBC on Power BI, right now I can see and connect all the table I have in my project but the table I need is not there still. Could this issue be because of the Google Sheets access settings, because it is not publicly accessible?

Comment: Power BI has a direct connector to BigQuery(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-connect-bigquery)

Comment: @James thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work because the table in BigQuery which I want to connect is a Google Sheets sourced table, so Power BI doesn't accept that I guess.

Answer (score 0):

As James mentioned, Power Bl has a direct connector to BigQuery [Connect to BigQuery in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-connect-bigquery). You should give it a try.

I read that Google BigQuery can query Google Sheets just like any other table. Look here:  [BigQuery and Google Sheets](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/how-to-crunch-your-business-data-from-sheets-in-bigquery). The MS documentation does not mention any limitation or restriction related to Google Sheets so I think there won't be any other issue.

Also, did you follow any tutorial or doc? Can you share it?

Comment: Hi @K_immer thank you for your answer! Yes, Power BI has a direct connection, I am using it generally and it works perfect for the local tables we have in our project. The problem here is that the table I am trying to connect is a Google Sheet connection created on BigQuery like you mentioned (it also works fine always), I also didn't see any limitation explanations about that but the only tables I cannot see during the Power BI connection are the tables which are Gsheets sourced ones. I followed this tutorial of MS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-connect-bigquery

Answer (score 0):

Some "Google resources” (projects, files, etc) tend to be hidden so external tools can't see or access to them, even when there is a connection between tools.

This user had a similar situation [BigQuery Sheets and Power BI connector](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/How-to-connect-BigQuery-Sheets-table-using-the-Power-BI/td-p/398543), take a look at it. They suggested to enable the Google Drive API so they can manipulate file's data.

Another similar situation was seen here [Connecting Google Sheets to Power BI](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/How-to-connect-google-sheet-to-Power-BI/td-p/14587), where they connected the Spreadsheet directly to Power BI. This is more related, as you prior mentioned, to the file's privacy settings.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. Those make sense totally, worst case directly connecting google sheets to power bi. Now I guess I need to ask my client to have a shared file with the option 'accessible by everyone with link' then it should be fine! Thank you again:)

Answer (score 0):

I have created connection power bi to big query engine using ODBC and Simba driver, here

I'm explaining the procedure

1) Download Simba driver for BigQuery from [Download](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/providers/simba-drivers/) and install

[image]

2) Search ODBC Driver (64bit) in the windows search bar

[image]

3) From that you click and move to system DNS, there you can find the Google Big Query Driver installed

[image]

4) Select Driver and Click configuration option then select OAuth Mechanism is **User Authentication** and click the sign-in button

[image]

5) It redirects to login and permission allow the window

[image]

6) Once you allowed then you will get a refresh token. Copy that one and past on ODBC driver refresh token text box and select your project to query and get the data

[image]

7) Go to Power bi and select get data option select ODBC driver, click connect option

[image]

8) Data source name as google big query and next text box leave blank and last text box write your query

[image]

9) finally you will get the result as given below.

[image]

Comment: It would be a perfect soluiton but It doesn't work for me. I do all the steps and it works until I paste the code in the Refresh Token  Box. Then I try to select the catalog and Power BI Says:

Authentication Failed: Invalid_grant